# access Windows shared folder with Xcode

Tags: windows, macos, xcode, shared-folders

I am developing some multiplatform software and have to develop, build and test on both, Windows and OS X.

Very often I am in the situation that I have made some changes on one OS, that almost certainly break something on the other one. For example the software supports more than 10 different target platforms and for some of them the binaries get built on Windows, for others on OS X, the same codebase is used in Visual Studio projects on Windows and in Xcode projects on OS X. So, when I for example add a new source file, it has of course to be added to all projects, or build scripts have to be run, to test, if everything still builds for every platform, and so on.

Doing this with version control is far from ideal:
Commit changes from one computer, update on the other, adust stuff, that can only be tested there, chck back in and update on first computer again, to see, if everything is still workign there - a lot of revision, in which something is broken for some platform.
We use version control (svn) to work with multiple developers on the same projects and therefor its fine, but its just not the right thing to share local work in progress stuff between two computers of the same developer.

So I am looking for a good solution to share the same local versions of the same files between two computers (with diffeerent OS). Basically as if one is accessing the same harddrive with both computers.

I have already tried with networking sharing my svn working copy on the windows machine to all machines in the network, that are logged in with my domain user account and then access this folder from the mac with smb, but sadly Xcode seems to have serious issues with this approach: more than 95% of the times, builds, that would normally be successful, fail, because Xcode fails to read-access some source-file in the shared folder. A few seconds later, without any changes, when trying the build another time, it processds the file just fine, but fails for another one, for which it had not problems the time before, and so on.
The solutions and workspaces of our software are medium sized, with several developers, a few dozens of projects, that depend on each other, and many hundreds of source files, so if for each source file I only get a read error in one of hundred tries, its still nearly impossible to rebuild half the Xcode workspace without a read acces error for any of the source files.

Are there any solutions out there for sharing folders, that do work more reliable with Xcode?